# Solve the equation $z^3-2z^2+3z-2=0.$

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, roots, quadratics, problem-solving

Solve the following equation.

$$z^3-2z^2+3z-2=0$$

If $a$ is a complex solution of this equation, what does $A$ equal?

$$A= \frac{|a|^2}{1-i ^ {43}}$$

It's on my exams and I really need to solve this on  to pass... Any help?

Comment: Do you mean $i^4\cdot 3$, or $i^{43}$?

Comment: What have you tried? $i^{43}=i^3=-i$, and $i^43=3$ so this seems strange?

Comment: Its i^43.i tried to fix it but it shows it like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $|z_{1}|=|z_{2}|=\sqrt{(\frac{1}{2})^{2}+(\frac{\pm\sqrt{7}}{2})^{2}}=\sqrt{2}$ and $i^{43}=(i^{2})^{21}i=-i$ we have $$A=\frac{|a|^{2}}{1+i}=\frac{2}{1+i}=\frac{2}{1+i}\times\frac{1-i}{1-i}=\frac{2(1-i)}{2}=1-i.$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $z^{3}-2z^{2}+3z-2=(z-1)(z^{2}-z+2)$. You get the complex (I mean non-real)  roots by solving then quadratic $z^{2}-z+2=0$.

Comment: Computing the roots is not even necessary.

Comment: If i do this i get 2 solutions. z1=1/2 +i(root7)/2 an z1=1/2 -i(root7)/2. Which one should i replace ?

Comment: @SamPeters They both give the same answer.

Comment: Pedantic terminology nit-pick: 1 is also a complex root. But no one uses "complex" like that, for some reasson.

Comment: @Arthur interesting comment.

Comment: (I am very sad that "irreal" or something similar is not an actual word.)

Comment: Hey guys, i do the replacement but i dont find a number that matches the possible answers. Can you please tell the solution so i can sumbit and get it over with this lesson ?Thaaank you

Comment: @Arthur can you please give me the solution ?